# Could not find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments

Tags: swift, swift-playground

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play


func getAverage(numbers: Int...) -> Double{
    var total = 0
    var average:Double = 0

    for number in numbers{
        total = total + number
    }

    average = total / numbers.count

    return average
}

getAverage(3, 6)
```

I get an error on `average = total / numbers.count`

> Could not find an overload for '/' that accepts the supplied arguments

I tried to fix by doing:

```
average = Double(total/numbers.count)
```

but then the getAverage was set to `4` instead of `4.5`

Comment: What about `average = Double(total)/Double(numbers.count)`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah That actually worked! Damn I was so close. Write it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

There are no such implicit conversions in Swift, so you'll have to explicitly convert that yourself:

```
average = Double(total) / Double(numbers.count)
```

From [***The Swift Programming Language***](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11): “Values are never implicitly converted to another type.” (Section: A Swift Tour)

But you're now using Swift, not Objective-C, so try to think in a more functional oriented way. Your function can be written like this:

```
func getAverage(numbers: Int...) -> Double {
    let total = numbers.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})
    return Double(total) / Double(numbers.count)
}
```

`reduce` takes a first parameter as an initial value for an accumulator variable, then applies the `combine` function to the accumulator variable and each element in the array. Here, we pass an anonymous function that uses `$0` and `$1` to denote the first and second parameters it gets passed and adds them up.

Even more concisely, you can write this: `numbers.reduce(0, +)`.

Note how type inference does a nice job of still finding out that `total` is an `Int`.

Answer (score 6):

The compiler picks an implementation of the `/` operator based on your input and output parameters. In your case the input parameters are two `Int` values and the output parameter is `Double`. This is what the compiler is looking for:

```
func / (left: Int, right: Int) -> Double
```

However, there is no such implementation of the `/` operator which is why you get the error. When you do `Double(total/numbers.count)`, your output parameter changes to `Int` which is why the compiler picks the following implementation for the `/` operator which exists:

```
func / (left: Int, right: Int) -> Int
```

This is why you get `4`instead of `4.5` as a result, even though you convert the result into a `Double` afterwards.

Your can provide your **own implementation** of the `/` operator which first converts your numbers into `Double`s:

```
func / (left: Int, right: Int) -> Double {
    return Double(left) / Double(right)
}
```

Then you can do the following:

```
let a: Int = 3
let b: Int = 2
let c: Double = a/b  // -> 1.5
```